# How to simplify for loop in prime number generator in python

Tags: python-2.7

```
import math

def is_prime(num):
    if num < 2:
        return False
    for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(num))+ 1):
        if num % i == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Primes seems to be a popular topic but in the book in which I am learning Python, I am on chpt 6 out of 21 and in the iteration chapter which it teaches while loops. I have not learned for loops yet although I understand what they do. So, let's say I have not learned for loops yet and am given only if/elif/else statements and the while loops as my tools. How can I change the for line of code into something more simple using the above tools? While asking this question I quickly came up with this code:

```
def formula(num):
    i = 2
    while i >= 2:
        return int(math.sqrt(num)+ 1)


def is_primetwo(num):
    i = 2
    if num < 2:
        return False
    formula(num)
    if num % i == 0:
        return False
    return True
```

It works but would this be a simple version of the for loop or is there something even more simple where I do not have to wrap a function within a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely, you do not need a function to replace a for loop.

So you've got this

```
for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(num))+ 1):
```

which is your for loop. Take a second to think what it's doing.

1.) It's taking the variable `i`, and it's starting it at a value of 2.

2.) It's checking whether to do the loop every time by checking if `i` is less than the (square root of `num`) plus 1

3.) Every time through the loop, it adds one to `i`.

We can do all of these things using a while loop.

Here's the original

```
for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(num))+ 1):
    if num % i == 0:
        return False
```

let's rename the second and third lines `loop contents` just so we're focusing on the looping part, not what logic we're doing with the variables `i` and `num`.

```
for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(num))+ 1):
    loop contents
```

ok, now let's just rearrange it to be a while loop. We need to set `i` to 2 first.

```
i = 2
```

Now we want to check that `i` is in the range we want

```
i = 2
while i <= int(math.sqrt(num) + 1):
    loop contents
```

Now we're almost set, we just need to make `i` actually change, instead of staying at a value of 2 forever.

```
i = 2
while i <= int(math.sqrt(num) + 1):
    loop contents
    i = i + 1
```

Your example seemed to do some of these elements, but this way is a simple way to do it, and no extra function is necessary. It could be the `range()` function that is confusing. Just remember, the for loop is doing three things; setting a variable to an initial value, checking a condition (one variable is less than another), and incrementing your variable to be one large than previously to run the loop again.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
from math import sqrt

def is_prime(num):
    if (num < 2):
        return False
    i = 2
    limit = int(sqrt(num) + 1)
    while (i <= limit):
        if num % i == 0:
            return False
        i = i + 1
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want, but the for loop:

```
for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(num))+ 1):
    if num % i == 0:
        return False
return True
```

can be expressed as:

```
i = 2
while i < int(math.sqrt(num))+ 1):
    if num % i == 0:
        return False
    i += 1
return True
```

Probably a good idea to determine `int(math.sqrt(num))+ 1)` once:

```
i = 2
n = int(math.sqrt(num))+ 1)
while i < n:
    if num % i == 0:
        return False
    i += 1
return True
```

Comment: Yes, I did ask how the for loop can be expressed using something more simple! Thank you